# Imacros (RegExp)

Tags: regex, numbers, extract, imacros

I've to extract a number from 4361 52 3610 35151 51

and i want to have only the 4361

code looks like this now

```
SET !VAR8 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\s/g, '')")
```

can someone tell me how can i start at the first white space and delete the other numbers?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might help you

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var index=s.indexOf(\"=\"); var index2=s.indexOf(\" \");var r=s.slice(index+1,index2);r;")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `iMacros` but this is the regex that will extract the first number for you :

```
(\b[0-9]+\b)
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/tV8vT5/1)